# Using a pre-minified Javascript library with jspm?

Tags: javascript, angular, client-side, systemjs, jspm

I am trying to do all my package management with JSPM, and I would like in some cases for the bundled minifed version of a library to be loaded by SystemJS instead of each individual source files (and I don't want to do the bundling myself with the JSPM CLI).

For example, I am doing the following:

`jspm install angular2`

And then I have a small application based on Angular2. When I look at what happens on the network, the browser loads a whole bunch of files that are part of Angular2, although in this particular case I would like to use angular2.dev.js, which is part of the angular2 module installed by JSPM (and maybe in production I would like to load something else).

Is there a way to do this with jspm (basically to replace bower + a script tag)?